# High active mongodb connections

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am using Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.3, MongoId Driver on Amazon EC2 with ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and 1.7 GB RAM.

> On each request, i see number of connections increase. see below
>   db.status()

```
connections:
{
   "current": NumberInt(17),
   "available": NumberInt(15983),
   "totalCreated": NumberLong(51) 
}
```

Currently, I have not specified anything related to pool size in mongoid.yml

> How i can use connection pool with mongoid in Rails 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the pool size to enable connection pooling for your environment.

```
production:
    pool_size: 5
```